# c# custom installer class .net 4.0 not called

Tags: c#, class, installation

I have c# custom installer class that originally targeted .net 2.0.
I have re-targeted it to .net 4.0, and now it does not seen to run.
I've proved this by adding Debugger.Break at relevent locations.

Under .net 2.0 the breakpoints are hit. I even tried targeting 3.5 and that worked.

I realise there a similar questions relating to this but the answers seem to suggest "wrong framework" or "use something else" variety.

Thanks!

Edit -

I have an  installer class

```
public partial class ScriptRunner : Installer
{...

public override void Install(System.Collections.IDictionary stateSaver)
{
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
   ...
```

This is tested by running the installer (i.e setup.exe). The break statement should cause a dialog to prompt to run the debugger. Under .net 2.0/3.5 this happens, but no under .net 4.0

Comment: Without seeing the code, this can't be answered. Please read this: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In .Net 4.0 the call to the debugger has been changed, this has thrown me off aswell at some point.

Changing

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
```

Into

```
System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Made it work for us, not sure if that also worked for 2.0 and 3.5 since we switched to 4.0 and stuck with it :)

Comment: Glad to help, don't forget to mark it as an answer for people who find this question in the future :)